# Sending curl requests from threads

Tags: c, multithreading, curl

I have written a program where the main function has two threads (thread1 and thread2) with individual curl objects initialized and then object shared as argument in the thread routine. The thread1 routine reads a file (say abc.txt) and uploads its contents to another file (say new.txt) on the local machine itself.
There is a condition included to check if uploaded file exists (i.e. new.txt), so that when thread2's routine is executed we can check if it is working properly but the contents do not get uploaded to the other file(newer.txt) 
if we do not use sleep() between creation of the threads.

What could be the reason that thread2 doesn't upload file contents without sleep.

I want to implement the same algorithm in a bigger module of 10 such threads and therefore I need it to be comparatively faster and more concurrent.

Comment: "*if it is working properly* what is working properly? And what do you consider "*working properly*". Also are `new.txt` and `newer.txt` different files or is this a typo and you mean the same? Better show the relevant code, then trying to explain it in words.

Comment: @alk By working properly I  meant, if the second thread is able to send curl requests and copy the contents of the file. new.txt and newer.txt are different files created to check if contents are being uploaded in both by the first and second thread respectively. I have used a check condition if new.txt exists then it creates a different file i.e. newer.txt for uploading contents of abc.txt by thread2.